# PowerShell: Loop through IIS 8+ server's custom log fields to check for existence of required fields

Tags: powershell, iis

I'm trying to loop through a list of servers (IIS 8.5 mostly) and for each server see if certain custom field names exist for logs. I'm executing these commands from my local machine, using the "invoke-command" cmdlet. Currently, it just returns to the cursor instead of writing out if there is a Match or No Match.

**srv.csv file contains:**
 - Host,IP
 - srv1,10.0.0.2
 - srv2,10.0.0.3

**log_stig.csv file contains:**
 - LogFieldName,SourceType
 - Connection,RequestHeader
 - User-Agent,RequestHeader
 - Content-Type,ResponseHeader

**Assigns the values  in srv.csv to $IISServers variable**

```
try{
  $IISServers = Import-Csv C:\Users\snappy\ps_script_resources\srv.csv
}
catch{
  "The file 'srv.csv' is not available"
}
```

**Assigns the values in log_stig.csv to $STIG_CustomFields variable**

```
try{
  $STIG_CustomFields = Import-Csv C:\Users\snappy\ps_script_resources\log_stig.csv
}catch{
  "The file 'log_stig.csv' is not available"
}
```

Loop through each server and then loop through each customfield name checking if they exist on the server.

```
ForEach($IISServer in $IISServers){
  $IISServerName = $($IISServer.Host)

  try{
    invoke-command -ComputerName $IISServerName -ScriptBlock{

    $SiteLogFileCustom = Get-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' - 
    filter "system.applicationHost/sites/site/logFile/customFields" -Name 'Collection'

    ForEach ($STIG_CustomField in $STIG_CustomFields){
      write-output $STIG_CustomField.LogFieldName
      write-output $SiteLogFileCustom.logFieldName
      if($STIG_CustomField.LogFieldName -match $SiteLogFileCustom.logFieldName){
        write-output "Match" 
      }
      else{
        write-output "No Match"
      }
      write-output "This ran"
    }
   }
  }
 catch{
  "Invoke failed for "
  }
}
```

The current code when I run from my local machine only returns to the cursor, I would expect that for every match, I would see either a Match or No Match message in my console. Any recommendations welcomed

Comment: `Invoke-Command -ComputerName` runs in a remote scope. So locally defined variables do not transition to that session. You can preface all those variables with `$using:` to gain access to them (read-only). An example is `$using:STIG_CustomFields`. I think updating this line --> `ForEach ($STIG_CustomField in $using:STIG_CustomFields){` will solve your problem.

Comment: That worked. Thank you